# New tab in IE appearing with black background

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer-10

I don't remember exactly what I customized/personalized in my system. The problem now is that  the '*New Tab*' in IE 10 is appearing with a black background as shown below:

[image: New Tab appearing with a black background]

How do I revert back/fix it to have the default white background?

**NOTE:** My system is running IE10 on Windows 7 32-bit.  I even tried changing different Themes (*Settings -> Control Panel -> Personalization*), but still the problem exists.

Answer (score 2):

Here's your fix:

Go to Personalize from your desktop, then change the theme to Windows 7 Basic - then change back to whatever theme you were using. No more black background!

Worked for me!

Answer (score 2):

We had the same issue on Windows 2008 R2 Xenapp 6 and 6.5 (terminal server). The issue can be fixed by applying the Windows 7 basic theme. But because our users could not modify the personalization (theme, background colors ...), we could not use this solution.

Using [Procmon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_Monitor), we found out that Internet Explorer 10 could not find the following registry key:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\DWM]
"ColorizationColor"
```

To fix the issue, we imported the following keys, which are usually set when the Windows 7 basic theme is selected, and our problem was solved:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\DWM]
"Composition"=dword:00000001
"ColorizationColor"=dword:6b74b8fc
"ColorizationColorBalance"=dword:00000008
"ColorizationAfterglow"=dword:6b74b8fc
"ColorizationAfterglowBalance"=dword:0000002b
"ColorizationBlurBalance"=dword:00000031
"ColorizationGlassReflectionIntensity"=dword:00000000
"ColorizationOpaqueBlend"=dword:00000000
```

Comment: +1 Thanks, this worked for me on Windows 7 Basic.

Comment: This worked immediately for me too on Windows 7 - Didn't even have to restart IE 11.

Answer (score 0):

There is a radical option: **Reset Internet Explorer settings**

1. open *Control Panel* > *Internet Options* or *Internet Explorer Tools menu* > *Internet Options*
2. click on *Advanced* tab
3. click on <kbd>Reset...</kbd> button
4. click on <kbd>Apply</kbd> button

The easier option would be to play with your *Appearance* properties

1. open *Control Panel* > *Internet Options* or *Internet Explorer
   Tools menu* > *Internet Options*
2. click on *General* tab
3. click on <kbd>Colors</kbd> button
4. tick the **Use Windows Colors** checkbox => the colors should be fine

[More Details here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-GB/internet-explorer/ie-accessibilty-options?ocid=IE10_ignore_colors#ie=ie-10-win-7)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  I tried both options, but still it is appearing with black background.  In fact, `Use Windows Colors` is already checked in my system. Any other idea/troubleshooting steps?